# Filter function for k elements larger than A

Tags: matlab, matrix

In R/Bioconductor's genefilter package, there is a nice function called [`kOverA` (page 18 in this manual)](http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/genefilter/man/genefilter.pdf).

It's just a filter method that, given a numerical matrix, removes the rows of that matrix that do not have `k`-elements that are greater than or equal to `A`-value.

How can I do the same thing in MATLAB?

---

Examples (simplified. In R, `kOverA` returns a function, so the actual syntax is a bit different but this is the functionality that I want):

```
m = [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
     0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1];

kOverA(m, A=1, k=0) → m  

kOverA(m, A=2, k=1) → empty 

kOverA(m, A=1, k=1) → [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
                       1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                       0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]

kOverA(m, A=1, k=4) → [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
                       1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                       0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]

kOverA(m, A=1, k=5) → [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                       0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
```

Comment: I edited your question and changed the word *"greater than"* to *"greater than or equal to"* to keep the wording consistent with your examples and R's `kOverA` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requires relational operator [`>=`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ge.html), [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) and this is it.

```
out = m(sum(m>=A,2) >= k,:);
```